# node.js - dictionary changes when passed to callback

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am using the async.map function to call a neo4j database on each element of "arrayOne".

```
    async.map(
        arrayOne,
        function(item, callback){
            getClientsNb({id:item},function (err, res) {
                if (err) {console.log(err); return callback(err);}
                console.log(res.results[0].data); //1
                callback(null,res.results[0].data);
            });
        }, 
        function(err,res) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(res); //2
        }
    )
```

The first console.log displays what I want:

> [ { row: [ 'DIE ZAUBERFLOETE-2013', 1355 ] } ]

But the second console.log in the final function does not display the same result:

> [ { row: [Object] } ],

Where does it come from? I would like to have the same result in the second console.log.

NB: the getClientsNb function is the following:

```
function getClientsNb(param, callback) {
    request.post({
        uri: httpUrlForTransaction,
        json: {statements: [{
            statement: 'MATCH (n:Show {id:{id}})<-[:BUYS]-(m) RETURN n.name, count(distinct m)', 
            parameters: param}]}
        },
    function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return callback(err)
        } else {
            return callback(null,body)
        }
    }).auth('neo4j', password, true);
}
```

Comment: Please change the second console.log() call to output the data as JSON, to display more details about what you are actually getting back:  `console.log("%j", res);`.

Comment: thank you, I did so and I found out that my result was actually passed to the last function, I just had to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED]

By changing the second console.log() call to output the data as JSON, you can display more details about what you are actually getting back: `console.log("%j", res);`. The result is probably in that `Object`.

### Additional issue

This may or may not not solve the issue you are asking about, but you do have a logic error with respect to error handling.

`async.map()` requires that its `callback` be called once for every item in the array. But in your code, if the anonymous callback passed to `getClientsNb()` is passed an `err` value, it returns without ever calling `callback`.

This code fixes the above issue:

```
async.map(
    arrayOne,
    function(item, callback){
        getClientsNb({id:item}, function (err, res) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); return callback(err); }
            console.log(res.results[0].data); //1
            callback(null,res.results[0].data);
        });
    }, 
    function(err,res) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(res); //2
    }
)
```

Comment: I have edited my post, thank you for your help. However it doesn't fix my issue.